# Get Process ID (pid) from NEPacketTunnelFlow & sourceAppAuditToken (Always nil)

Tags: swift, macos, network-programming, networkextension

I implemented a per-app vpn with packetTunnelProvider on MacOS, fully functional. I would like to get the PID from sourceAppAuditToken but it is always nil.

This is the code:

```
self.packetFlow.readPacketObjects { packets in
            for packet in packets {                
                if let auditToken = packet.metadata!.sourceAppAuditToken {
                  log.debug("ok")
                } else {
                  log.debug("No audit Token")
                }
            }
        }
```

I read a lot of answer about this problem but all solved on NEFilterFlow and they don't actually work on PacketTunnelFlow

Comment: Hello, I am implementing the same looking forward for a small help. 

I'm doing this without MDM. means I'm in Testing Per App VPN mode. let's connect to help each other

Answer (score 0):

please replace

```
packet.metadata!.sourceAppAuditToken
```

with

```
packet.metadata?.sourceAppUniqueIdentifier
```

and verify if it is nil or not.

> if packet.metadata?.sourceAppUniqueIdentifier == nil {
> per App VPN is not implemented properly  }